# Implement own TrustManager in Javascript (Rhino engine)

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am trying to do implement my own TrustManager in Javascript, but I have no idea how to implement it.

In Java I have the following :

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to use the following for the X509TrustManager :

```
js> obj = { getAcceptedIssuers : function() { return null; }, checkClientTrusted: function() { }, checkServerTrusted: function() { } }
[object Object]
js> x509tm = new javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager(obj)
adapter1@2eee9593
js>
```

Then I dont know how to create the TrustManager. How to do this in Javascript (Rhino 1.6 release 7 2008 01 02)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours, I finally managed to implement it.

Here is the code corresponding to above Java part :

```
    obj = { getAcceptedIssuers : function() { return null; }, checkClientTrusted: function() { return; }, checkServerTrusted: function() { return; } };
var o = new JavaAdapter(javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager, obj);
var oo = new Array();
oo.push(o);
```

Then to use it, everything becomes easy :

```
var sc = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, oo, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Hope this will help somebody in the same situation.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on user2360915's answer, an alternate way of extending a class within Rhino is to use the format:

```
new ClassType({NewFunction:function(){}})
```

For example:

```
var HNV = new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier({ verify:function(hostname,session){return true;} });
```

This produces a slightly different initial approach to user2360915's (although it requires the same Array solution to work):

```
var ExtendedTrustManager = new javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager({accepted:null,checkClientTrusted:function(xcs, string){},checkServerTrusted:function(xcs, string){this.accepted = xcs;},getAcceptedIssuers:function(){return this.accepted;}});

var TMArray = new Array();

TMArray.push(ExtendedTrustManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

The full code to be used on Mirth adapted from https://nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
 obj = { getAcceptedIssuers : function() { return null; }, checkClientTrusted: function() { return; }, checkServerTrusted: function() { return; } };
var o = new JavaAdapter(javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager, obj);
var oo = new Array();
oo.push(o);

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
var sc = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, oo, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());


 // Create all-trusting host name verifier
       

var allHostsValid = new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
             verify: function(hostname, session) {
                return true;
            }
        };


 
// Install the all-trusting host verifier

      javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```